# how do i automate blog post to my website (VS)

Tags: java, html, css, automation, blogs

I'm setting up my new blog, and want to automate my posting of my blog without letting the editor have there hands on the code?

This is for a Blog about the environment, every week i collect an average of 84 articles which is enough for 1 article post every 2 hours.

I was thinking numerous times of using wix, but that software is very limited so instead i use Html, css and java with Visual studio code.

Also when the automated blog post is posted i want it to auto update the homepage with the article and also i want to do it for all 84 as i am goign to que them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most easiest method is to find a blogging platform such as [Blogger](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/getting_started#background-operations) that provides a public API. You can then use the API to do the sort of automation that you want.

Comment: yes ik that but i think its very restrictive, so i want to automate it with VS.

Comment: What do you mean by restrictive?